# docsplit gem issue

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Hi I  want to make a screenshot of each page of an uploaded document, pdf

so I installed the Docsplit gem (http://documentcloud.github.com/docsplit/) yesterday (together with all the dependencies) and I wanted to test this quickly so I tried one of the examples of your documentation (in commandline)

```
docsplit images example.pdf
```

and this was the outputted error:

> execvp failed, errno = 2 (No such file
>   or directory) gm convert: "gs" "-q"
>   "-dBATCH" "-dMaxBitmap=50000000"
>   "-dNOPAUSE" "-sDEVICE=ppmraw"
>   "-dTextAlphaBits=4"
>   "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4" "-r150x150"
>   "-dFirstPage=1" "-dLastPage=1"
>   "-sOutputFile=/var/folders/um/umOJP4yeEoG4UihNlcD7ME+++TM/-Tmp-/d20110325-6084-j35i1w/gmrpht13"
>   "--"
>   "/var/folders/um/umOJP4yeEoG4UihNlcD7ME+++TM/-Tmp-/d20110325-6084-j35i1w/gm04N0rO"
>   "-c" "quit". gm convert: Postscript
>   delegate failed (example.pdf).

I'm not sure why it says No such file or directory because I'm absolutely sure the file exists.

Also I'm trying out the method in a ruby script (usually I only use gems in a Ruby on Rails project, so this might be a stupid error)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'docsplit'

CUR_DIR = Dir.getwd
DOCS_DIR = "#{CUR_DIR}/docs"
THUMB_DIR = "#{CUR_DIR}/thumbnails"

Dir.mkdir DOCS_DIR unless File.directory? DOCS_DIR
Dir.mkdir THUMB_DIR unless File.directory? THUMB_DIR

Dir.chdir(DOCS_DIR)
Dir["*"].each do |filename|
  # skip directories
  next if File.directory? filename

  puts "processing #{filename}"  
  Docsplit.extract_images(filename, :size => '920x', :format => [:png, :jpg])
end
```

NameError: uninitialized constant Docsplit

Note I'm using docsplit (0.5.0) and ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin10]

Would anyone happend know what's causing this problem and what would possibly fix this issue?

If anyone knows a ruby alternative for making images of pdfs and documents, please share. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the error message closely:

> execvp failed, errno = 2 (No such file or directory) gm convert: "gs" "-q"
>   ...
>   gm convert: Postscript delegate failed (example.pdf).

The message is telling you that the PostScript builder failed because it couldn't find GhostScript (`gs`). So, you need to install [GhostScript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/), probably from [MacPorts](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/print/ghostscript).

Comment: wonderful, this fixed the first part indeed. Have you got any idea why I get the ruby error: NameError: uninitialized constant Docsplit

Comment: @Ayrton: I don't have a Docsplit installation handy so I can't check but it looks like it should work. The "unitialized constant" thing is what you get when Ruby can't find a class or module and [`extract_images`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/docsplit/0.5.0/Docsplit.extract_images) should be in `Docsplit` and `Docsplit` should be in  the `docsplit` library.

Comment: that's what I thought too, hence the require 'docsplit' and Docsplit.extract_images. However I keep producing the 'DNameError: uninitialized constant Docsplit' error

Comment: What happens if you do this in `irb`: `require 'docsplit'; Docsplit.class`?

Comment: no such file to load -- Docsplit, I just checked the gem is installed at /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems through rubygems, which I installed through macports

Comment: That means that `irb` can't find your library. Check your Ruby search paths and check the ownership and permissions on all the installed Docsplit files and directories.